# I want to create bat file, The Selenium Project is been developed using TESTNG and Java. I have suite in xml.

Tags: testing, automation, testng

Now i want to create bat file, Please file in creating bat file.

I don't have main function in my project.

I want to run the test suite in Main class. How can i do that ? Source code please.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your xml from main function.

I can provide source code, but it is against policy of stackOverflow.

first show your research.

I think many might have answered this.

Hint: use TestNG class
and add XMLTest, XMLSuite and XMLClass objects to it.